# Azure BotFramework C#| Persisting chat history if user opens bot in different tabs

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, web-chat

I'm working on QnA Maker Bot. I have provided various links in the answers which direct to different pages of the website where bot is deployed. My requirement is that if the users open a link in new tab then their chat history must be continued in the other tab too.

Comment: what channel are you using? If it is webchat, then there is a similar issue which is open https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/3156 and https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/4174

Comment: @ranusharao  I'm using Direct Line..